# NGINX + PHP-FPM - Should I keep them in separate containers or not?

Tags: php, nginx, docker

This question is more about convention really. Currently I have two containers, one for NGINX (using the [NGINX maintained image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)) and one for my application which is a custom image but has PHP-FPM running on it. They currently communicate using Port Forwarding and it's working just fine.

Recently I was asked that since both of those containers require the same volume to be mounted, does it make more sense to combine both processes into one container? Is there any clear cut benefit to keeping them separate and sharing resources or should I consolidate the two?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that your current setup is working just fine, I would recommend leaving it as-is.

With that said, you also mentioned that both need the same volume. Putting code into a volume is not advised and does introduce some challenges.

There are some codebases that do treat their codebase as stateful data (think wordpress with its themes and plugins system). If your application fits into this category, then you should have it in a volume. Since there is a volume involved, having multiple containers access it is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks! I should've clarified, I'm currently working on a dev machine which is why I have the volumes mounted. My production build will not have volumes. So given the fact that in production I would need both containers to have a copy of the code, does _that_ throw any red flags?

Comment: not necessarily. If I want to deploy 10 instances of my app, I expect each of them will have a copy of the code. My nginx container might contain just the static files for my app. I'd want to devise a process to deploy both in lockstep. Other than that, it isn't a big deal.